# How to configure a splash page for squid?

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-16.04, squid

I have a problem configuraing a page for redirecting the first acces via `Squid` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Here is the relevent configuration under `/etc/squid/squid.conf`. I tried to follow the example from the docs and from the net.

```
external_acl_type splash_page %SRC /usr/lib/squid/ext_session_acl -b /var/lib/squid/session.db
acl existing_users external splash_page
deny_info 511:/etc/squid/splash.html existing_users
http_access deny !existing_users
```

`Squid` starts and then exists with the following

```
# service squid status
● squid.service - LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/squid; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since dim. 2017-10-29 15:29:47 CET; 1min 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7814 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/squid stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4616 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/squid reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7833 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/squid start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

oct. 29 15:29:54 localhost (squid-1)[7913]: The splash_page helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!
oct. 29 15:29:54 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7913 exited with status 1
oct. 29 15:29:57 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7925 started
oct. 29 15:29:57 localhost (squid-1)[7925]: The splash_page helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!
oct. 29 15:29:57 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7925 exited with status 1
oct. 29 15:30:00 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7942 started
oct. 29 15:30:00 localhost (squid-1)[7942]: The splash_page helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!
oct. 29 15:30:00 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7942 exited with status 1
oct. 29 15:30:00 localhost squid[7882]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 7942 will not be restarted due to repeated, frequent failures
oct. 29 15:30:00 localhost squid[7882]: Exiting due to repeated, frequent failures
```

The files are existing and (I think) configured with the good rights:

```
# ll /usr/lib/squid/ext_session_acl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10208 juil. 26 15:11 /usr/lib/squid/ext_session_acl*
# ll /etc/squid/splash.html
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 11 oct.  29 11:18 /etc/squid/splash.html
# ll /var/lib/squid/session.db
-rw-r----- 1 proxy root 1 oct.  29 13:43 /var/lib/squid/session.db
```

What am I missing ? It's the first time I use `squid` so I hope I'm not asking a dumb question.